# How to concatenate columns in previous row in dataframe?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, functional-programming

I have a dataframe like this:

```
case class CC(id: String, p2: Double, p3: Double, time: Int)
val df = List(
  CC("a", 1.1d, 2.2d, 1),
  CC("b", 3.3d, 4.4d, 2),
  CC("c", 5.5d, 6.6d, 3)).toDF

+---+---+---+----+
| id| p2| p3|time|
+---+---+---+----+
|  a|1.1|2.2|   1|
|  b|3.3|4.4|   2|
|  c|5.5|6.6|   3|
+---+---+---+----+
```

I want to concatenate `p2` and `p3` of previous row and place in column `p5` and concatenate `p2` and `p3` of current row and place in column `p6`. To get:

```
    +---+---+---+----+---------+---------+
    | id| p2| p3|time| p5      | p6      |
    +---+---+---+----+---------+---------+
    |  a|1.1|2.2|   1|         |1.1: 2.2 |
    |  b|3.3|4.4|   2|1.1: 2.2 |3.3: 4.4 |
    |  c|5.5|6.6|   3|3.3: 4.4 |5.5: 6.6 |
    +---+---+---+----+---------+---------+
```

For current row, i.e. `p6` I can easily use

```
.withColumn("p6", concat(col("p2"), col("p3")))
```

and for the previous row, I thought about using a window function and `lag` like below, but it does not work.

```
val wf = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time")
df.withColumn("p5", concat(lag(col("p2"), 1) + lag("p3", 1)).over(w))
```

But I get the error that expression `concat...` not supported within a window function. Some [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427511/spark-sql-unable-to-use-aggregate-within-a-window-function) talk about using a user defined aggregate function, but I could not find a simple example that I could follow.

Any explanation on this problem is really appreciated. Please suggest alternate methods to solve this problem if you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give similar example but not the same as you have..
if you want to apply concat on 2 lag columns you can go by 2 steps like below...
1) apply lag functions
2) then concat.

*you cant apply concat on 2 lag columns at the same time...*

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  var customers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("Alice", "click","item_8", 50),
    ("Alice", "view","item_2", 55),
    ("Alice", "share","item_11", 100),
    ("Bob", "view","item_11", 25),
    ("Bob", "share","ietm_2", 50),
    ("Bob", "view", "item_8",65))).toDF("name", "event", "item", "time")
  customers.show

  val wSpec3 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("time")
  customers.withColumn(
    "prev_event", lag(col("event"),1).over(wSpec3)
  ).withColumn(
    "prev_item", lag(col("item"),1).over(wSpec3)
  ).withColumn(
    "prev_time", lag(col("time"),1).over(wSpec3)
  ).withColumn("newcolumn", concat( 'prev_event, 'prev_item)).show
```

Result :

```
+-----+-----+-------+----+
| name|event|   item|time|
+-----+-----+-------+----+
|Alice|click| item_8|  50|
|Alice| view| item_2|  55|
|Alice|share|item_11| 100|
|  Bob| view|item_11|  25|
|  Bob|share| ietm_2|  50|
|  Bob| view| item_8|  65|
+-----+-----+-------+----+

+-----+-----+-------+----+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
| name|event|   item|time|prev_event|prev_item|prev_time|  newcolumn|
+-----+-----+-------+----+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
|  Bob| view|item_11|  25|      null|     null|     null|       null|
|  Bob|share| ietm_2|  50|      view|  item_11|       25|viewitem_11|
|  Bob| view| item_8|  65|     share|   ietm_2|       50|shareietm_2|
|Alice|click| item_8|  50|      null|     null|     null|       null|
|Alice| view| item_2|  55|     click|   item_8|       50|clickitem_8|
|Alice|share|item_11| 100|      view|   item_2|       55| viewitem_2|
+-----+-----+-------+----+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very easy to understand and it answers my question. 
Additionally, it would be nice if you could answer these questions. Will the creating of column with lag value and the column with concatenated value happen in one pass of the df or require two separate passes? 
Also, if I drop the columns with the lag value (after creating the final concatenated cols), will spark drop the columns after materializing (which will take more memory) or can it drop them after creating each new row? Thanks.

Comment: see the explain plan for better understanding of how it happens internally, dropping can be done anytime once you have previous  information.

Comment: Yes of course, I already upvoted it. I was waiting for some time before accepting the answer, to not discourage others from coming up with a better solution (not that this solution is less good). Thanks again.